# Join Supplier name and Supplier number using two queries

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a two queries.

```
  select a.supplier_nbr
     from co_global_duns_xref_t a,
          co_global_duns_t b     
    where
     a.global_duns_nbr=b.global_duns_nbr(+)
```

and

```
select supplier_name_txt
from (
        select supplier_nbr,supplier_name_txt, source_system_id, 
               row_number() over (order by source_system_id) precedence_nbr
        from   er_supplier_t 
        where  source_system_id in (
                                        SELECT source_system_id
                                        FROM   co_source_system_t
                                        where  active_flag = 'Y' and
                                               erp_version_cd = '3.1' 
                                   ) and
              -- supplier_nbr = '211394790'   
      )
where precedence_nbr = 1
```

From the first query I will get supplier nbr . for that supplier nbr i need to search a supplier name in the second and display both.
please tell me how to do that?

Comment: The question is not really clear to me. Are you saying that you'd like the **a.supplier_nbr** column from the first query to be joined with **supplier_name_txt** from the second query?

Comment: Your last 2 lines are not getting it,explain it properly and well formated.

Comment: From the first query I will get supplier nbr .
for that supplier nbr i need to search a supplier name in the second and display both..

Answer (score 0):

```
select supplier_name_txt
from (
        select supplier_nbr,supplier_name_txt, source_system_id, 
               row_number() over (order by source_system_id) precedence_nbr
        from   er_supplier_t 
        where  source_system_id in (
                                        SELECT source_system_id
                                        FROM   co_source_system_t
                                        where  active_flag = 'Y' and
                                               erp_version_cd = '3.1' 
                                   ) and
               supplier_nbr = '211394790'  ---   
      ) a join co_global_duns_xref_t b on a.supplier_nbr = b.supplier_nbr
where precedence_nbr = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little confused by the question, but I'll take a shot at answering it.  You should be able to put the first query inside the second one and then join by the supplier numbers.

```
SELECT supplier_nbr,
       supplier_name_txt
  FROM (SELECT er.supplier_nbr,
               supplier_name_txt, 
               source_system_id, 
               row_number() over (PARTITION BY er.supplier_nbr ORDER BY source_system_id) precedence_nbr
          FROM er_supplier_t er,
               (SELECT a.supplier_nbr
                  FROM co_global_duns_xref_t a,
                       co_global_duns_t b     
                 WHERE a.global_duns_nbr=b.global_duns_nbr(+)
               ) a
         WHERE source_system_id IN (SELECT source_system_id
                                      FROM co_source_system_t
                                     WHERE active_flag = 'Y' 
                                       AND erp_version_cd = '3.1' 
                                   ) 
           AND er.supplier_nbr = a.supplier_nbr
  )
 WHERE precedence_nbr = 1
```

I also had to change the row_number analytic function to partition by supplier_nbr